# Pre-populated text in Table Cell showing as "undefined" when HTML tags are added in JS

Tags: javascript, html

I am stuck. I have a Frakenstein'ed code from here and there to garner a desired result. This JS code is used on a table (shown below) that is generated from a separate program (CMS Supervisor) which outputs to an HTML file based on a script that loops every 5 seconds. Therein the Table elements are static.

There is a page_template.htm that CMS reads before it writes the actual HTML file page_.htm and inserts the table into plus any extra coding...the table is written within the following tags:

```
<CVSUP_BODY></CVSUP_BODY> \\ Within these tags is where the JS code has to be placed on the template in order to be pulled from the template and placed on the actual page_htm that is viewed.
```

I created a Fiddle however, and for some reason the blink has no effect (may be a setting in the Frameworks and Extensions that I have selected inaccurately). Nevertheless, I made a test_page.htm and can get everything to work with the exception of having the text in the "Oldest Call Waiting" displaying "undefined", it blinks and highlights the BG according to the cases, but it will not display the actual text (time duration) that should be there.

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SoL33t/3jXmb/12/) ...any help would be greatly appreciated. If there is anything that I have left out please let me know.

P.S. I know "blink" is a sour subject on this and many other forums, so I want to assure anyone with that sour taste for this function that this property is not being used for the public domain and is only being utilized to draw attention to calls holding over 2:00 minutes in a Call Center Call Queue. :)

JS:

```
 function formatCells(table) {
 var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0],
    cells = tbody.getElementsByTagName('td'),
    colors = ['red', 'black', 'white'],
    blinkme = "<blink>" + cells.textContent + "</blink>";
```

I have also tried (to no avail):

```
blinkme = "<blink>",
blinkme += cells.textContent,
blinkme += "</blink>";
```

JS continued:

```
for (var c = 0, len = cells.length; c < len; c++) {
    if (cells[c].cellIndex > 1) {
        switch (parseInt((cells[c].textContent || cells[c].innerText), 10)) {
            case 1:
                cells[c].style.backgroundColor = colors[2];
                cells[c].style.color = colors[1];
                break;
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 4:
            case 5:
                cells[c].style.backgroundColor = colors[0];
                cells[c].style.color = colors[2];
                cells[c].style.fontWeight = '900';
                cells[c].innerHTML = blinkme;
                break;
        }
      }
   }
}

formatCells(document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0]);

function blinkIt() {
   if (!document.all) return;
   else {
      for (i = 0; i < document.all.tags('blink').length; i++) {
        s = document.all.tags('blink')[i];
        s.style.visibility = (s.style.visibility == 'visible') ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
    }
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
 <TABLE BORDER=1 CELLPADDING=1 CELLSPACING=0>
    <TR>
        <TH>Skill</TH>
        <TH>Calls Waiting</TH>
        <TH>Oldest Call</TH>
    </TR>
    <TR ALIGN=RIGHT>
        <TD ALIGN=LEFT>Affiliates</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>2</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>2:01</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR ALIGN=RIGHT>
        <TD ALIGN=LEFT>Agent Other</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>0</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>:00</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR ALIGN=RIGHT>
        <TD ALIGN=LEFT>Agent to Agent Inbou</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>0</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>:00</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR ALIGN=RIGHT>
        <TD ALIGN=LEFT>Agent Web Assist</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>0</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>:00</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR ALIGN=RIGHT>
        <TD ALIGN=LEFT>Agt D Supplies</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>0</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>:00</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR ALIGN=RIGHT>
        <TD ALIGN=LEFT>Agt D Contracting</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>0</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>2:00</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR ALIGN=RIGHT>
        <TD ALIGN=LEFT>Agt D Other</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>0</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>:00</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR ALIGN=RIGHT>
        <TD ALIGN=LEFT>Agt D Scheduling</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>0</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>4:00</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR ALIGN=RIGHT>
        <TD ALIGN=LEFT>AOR Agent</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>0</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>:00</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR ALIGN=RIGHT>
        <TD ALIGN=LEFT>AOR CB</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>0</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>:00</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR ALIGN=RIGHT>
        <TD ALIGN=LEFT>AOR Other</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>0</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>:00</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR ALIGN=RIGHT>
        <TD ALIGN=LEFT>AOR Sales</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>0</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>:00</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR ALIGN=RIGHT>
        <TD ALIGN=LEFT>AOR_LTD Sales</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>0</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>:00</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR ALIGN=RIGHT>
        <TD ALIGN=LEFT>Appointment Setting</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>0</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>:00</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR ALIGN=RIGHT>
        <TD ALIGN=LEFT>Career Recruiting</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>0</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>:00</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR ALIGN=RIGHT>
        <TD ALIGN=LEFT>Co 011</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>0</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>:00</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR ALIGN=RIGHT>
        <TD ALIGN=LEFT>Escalation</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>0</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>:00</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR ALIGN=RIGHT>
        <TD ALIGN=LEFT>Executive Operators</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>0</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>:00</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR ALIGN=RIGHT>
        <TD ALIGN=LEFT>Mktr Other</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>0</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>:00</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR ALIGN=RIGHT>
        <TD ALIGN=LEFT>Mktr Sched</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>0</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>:00</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR ALIGN=RIGHT>
        <TD ALIGN=LEFT>Other Benefit Verif</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>0</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>:00</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR ALIGN=RIGHT>
        <TD ALIGN=LEFT>Other Claim Status</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>0</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>:00</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR ALIGN=RIGHT>
        <TD ALIGN=LEFT>Other Other</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>0</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>:00</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR ALIGN=RIGHT>
        <TD ALIGN=LEFT>Other UW Interview</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>0</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>:00</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR ALIGN=RIGHT>
        <TD ALIGN=LEFT>Part D Esc</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>0</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>:00</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR ALIGN=RIGHT>
        <TD ALIGN=LEFT>Rx Other</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>0</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>:00</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR ALIGN=RIGHT>
        <TD ALIGN=LEFT>Rx Sched</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>0</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>:00</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR ALIGN=RIGHT>
        <TD ALIGN=LEFT>Spanish</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>0</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>2:01</TD>
    </TR>
</TABLE>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`('td').textContent` on line 5 of the fiddle is undefined. You'll need to change `cells[c].innerHTML = blinkme` to something like `cells[c].innerHTML = '<blink>' + cells[c].textContent + '</blink>'`;

In the blinkIt method, you can use querySelectorAll to gather the blink tags like this:

```
var blinkTags = document.querySelectorAll('blink');
for (i = 0; i < blinkTags.length; i++) {
    s = blinkTags[i];
    s.style.visibility = (s.style.visibility == 'visible') ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
}
```

Also in the fiddle, the blinkIt method is undefined at the time of the body's onload event. You'll have to set the interval when the blinkIt function is defined. I'll leave that one up to you.

Comment: You Sir, are my hero of the day.

Comment: cells[c].innerHTML = ("<blink>" + cells[c].innerText + "</blink>"); ...was the trick, Thank you!